# Why I got AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'label_map'

Tags: python, tensorflow-lite, nonetype

I am new to ML and CV filed.
Just used Train a salad detector with TensorFlow Lite Model Maker on colab to train my custom model for tensorflow lite.
But got this problem.

> **AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'label_map'**

Here is the code.

```py
!pip install -q tflite-model-maker
!pip install -q pycocotools 

import numpy as np
import os

from tflite_model_maker.config import ExportFormat
from tflite_model_maker import model_spec
from tflite_model_maker import object_detector

import tensorflow as tf
assert tf.__version__.startswith('2')

tf.get_logger().setLevel('ERROR')
from absl import logging
logging.set_verbosity(logging.ERROR)

spec = model_spec.get('efficientdet_lite2')

train_data, validation_data, test_data = object_detector.DataLoader.from_csv('gs://zmlcoral/strips/export_data-untitled_1629418661144-2021-08-20T01:44:38.803321Z/image_object_detection_1.csv')
```

**my dataset from google cloud**

```
model = object_detector.create(train_data, model_spec=spec, batch_size=8, train_whole_model=True, validation_data=validation_data)
```

**and the error happened here**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-187f39c1697e> in <module>()
----> 1 model = object_detector.create(train_data, model_spec=spec, batch_size=8, train_whole_model=True, validation_data=validation_data)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_examples/lite/model_maker/core/task/object_detector.py in create(cls, train_data, model_spec, validation_data, epochs, batch_size, train_whole_model, do_train)
    281           model_spec.compat_tf_versions, compat.get_tf_behavior()))
    282 
--> 283     object_detector = cls(model_spec, train_data.label_map, train_data)
    284 
    285     if do_train:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'label_map'
```

Can anyone please help me to solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Obviously `train_data` is `None`.  So either check for that, or else try to find out why it's `None` and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work with these settings from python csv writer. I also recommend using the full global path, as using the relative path for the files didn't seem to work :(

```
import csv
import glob

# the headings for the google models
train_marker = 'TRAIN,'
test_marker  = 'TEST,'
val_marker   = 'VALIDATION,'

# default bounding box encapsulating image
b_box = '0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,1.0'

train = glob.glob("yourpath/train/*.jpg")
test  = glob.glob("yourpath/test/*.jpg")
val   = glob.glob("yourpath/val/*.jpg")


with open('droneData.csv', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as csvfile:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csvfile, quotechar = '\'',delimiter=',',quoting = csv.QUOTE_NONE,escapechar = ' ')
                        
    for file_path in train:
        csv_writer.writerow([train_marker +  file_path + ',' + label + b_box])

    for file_path in test:
        csv_writer.writerow([test_marker + '/' + file_path + ',' + label + b_box])

    for file_path in val:
        csv_writer.writerow([val_marker + '/' + file_path + ',' + label + b_box])
```